# Coq: Sublists of sorted lists are also sorted?

Tags: coq

I am trying to prove that if a list (L1 ++ a :: L2) that is StronglySorted by "less than or equal to" means that the list (L1 ++ L2) is also sorted (since it's just a sorted list minus an element). So far I have

```
Definition sorted := (StronglySorted (λ x y, x ≤ y)).
Lemma sorted_sublist : ∀ (L1 L2 : list Z) (a : Z), 
                      sorted (L1 ++ a :: L2) ⇒ sorted (L1 ++ L2).
Proof.
  intros.
  induction L1.
  - simpl.
    simpl in H.
    apply StronglySorted_inv in H.    
    destruct H.
    exact H.
  - apply StronglySorted_inv in H.
    destruct H.
    apply IHL1 in H.
    apply SSorted_cons.
    exact H.
    fold (L1 ++ L2).
    fold (L1 ++ a :: L2) in H0.
```

And I'm left with 
[hypotheses and goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wY7Yq.png).
Any ideas how to finish the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first convince yourself informally that this hypothesis you have (modulo the notation)

```
H0 : Forall (fun y : Z => (a0 <= y)%Z) (L1 ++ a :: L2)
```

implies the goal

```
Forall (fun y : Z => (a0 <= y)%Z) (L1 ++ L2)
```

so you're on the right path. The above implication is provable by another induction on `L1`.

This approach is justified because `StronglySorted` is actually defined similarly by double induction: every suffix is strongly sorted (first induction) and the head is smaller than the other elements (second induction for each step of the first).

Comment: Thanks for the tip Li-yao! I'm still having trouble manipulating the base and inductive cases in that second induction. For example, is there a built-in function that yields: `Forall {y : Z | a0 ≤ y} (a :: L2) ⇒ Forall {y : Z | a0 ≤ y} L2` ?

Comment: Rather than a function, you can use the definition of `Forall` here. `intro HL2; inversion HL2.`.

Comment: I tried inversion, I hadn't heard of that command before! If you don't mind me asking, what do I after that? [Hypotheses and goal](https://imgur.com/a/IY4Yk2a)

Comment: Now your goal is of the form `Forall P (x :: xs)`, which holds if and only if `P x` and `Forall P xs` hold. This step is carried out by the `constructor.` tactic.